# Windows Double Click behavior

Tags: windows, mouse, double-click

Is there a way to change the double-click behavior in Windows?

What appears to happen:
if the time between *initially* pushing down the button the first time and *initially* pushing down the button the second time is short enough a double-click is registered *immediately* as the second click happens

Issue:
Often I intend to highlight several files and move them simultaneously. If i don't pause long enough between selecting the last file and moving the lot of them an unwanted double-click is registered.
Or I accidentally double click when I don't mean to but as soon as the button is pressed the second time (before I release the button) the double-click is registered.
Or I sustain the first click (maybe verifying that I'm selecting the correct file) then when I click the second time it has been too long since I pressed the button the first time (even though I have just released the button after the first press) and the wanted double-click is not registered.

What I'd like to have happen:
Have Windows use the time between *releasing* the mouse for double click.

Difference:
If I'm moving multiple files I can select the last file then click-and-hold (immediately afterwards) to grab and move the files.
If I accidentally double click (which I usually realize before I release the mouse button the second time) I can hold the mouse button down and 'cancel' the double-click.
If I sustain the first click I can still double click by clicking a second time immediately afterwards.

Can this be changed?

Also welcome is reasoning why the current way is better since I don't see an advantage.

Comment: Though you can change the *timing* between clicks to be registered as a double-click, you'd need to rewrite the OS to change event from WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONDOWN to the UP versions. In GNOME or other compiled UI, that would be trivial, but not MS proprietary Windows.

Comment: Hey! Nice question. This behaviour can be simulated with Autohotkey. I'll try this out.